# Does $\pi:\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ have a smooth right inverse?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $\pi: \mathbb S^2 \to \mathbb {RP}^2$ be the projection map. I understand $\pi$ is smooth. Ideally I should use the tangent space, but this only tells me for $x \in \mathbb{S}^2$ that
$$\pi_{*,x}:T_x \mathbb{S}^2 \to T_{\pi(x)} \mathbb{R}P^2 $$ is an isomorphism, but I dont know how to use this to construct an inverse for $\pi$.

Edit: Im sorry,The original question was too long for the title, here is a more precise statement

> Let $\pi$ be the projection map $\pi:\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$, does there exist $s: \mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ such that $\pi \circ s = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}P^2}$?

Comment: The map $\pi$ can't have an inverse since it is two-to-one. Are you sure the question isn't asking whether it has a smooth section instead?

Comment: @hunter I edited the question a bit, do I make myself more clear? Sorry, first time posting

Comment: that makes sense! a lot of people would use the word "section" rather than "inverse" for that. Anyway, it doesn't exist from thinking about the fundamental group (not even a continuous section). Are you required to use arguments from differential topology?

Comment: We haven't covered yet the fundamental group in my course. The last things we studied was the tangent space, submersions,  immersions, submanifolds, and the level set covering theorem

Comment: It sounds like your tools, along with what you wrote above, are enough to show that such $s$ must be a diffeomorphism with inverse $\pi$, a contradiction. You’ll use connectedness and compactness of the spaces involved.

Comment: Just a small comment: Nothing to do with smoothness here. There is no *continuous* section. Try it even for $S^1\to\Bbb RP^1$. In general, this is an exercise in basic algebraic topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to argue by contradiction. If a smooth map $\sigma$ with the required properties would exist, then it cannot be surjective. Hence $\sigma(\mathbb RP^2)\subset S^2$ would be a non-empty, proper subset. But from the construction, it is easy to deduce that this subset is both open and closed in $S^2$ which contradicts the fact that $S^2$ is connected.